# Convert image to sketch using php imagick

Tags: php, imagick

Trying to achieve sketch effect using php, but unable to get desired output.

Tried with

```
$im1->sketchimage(2, 1, -20);
```

but getting blur sort of image only.

Also, looked out and found

```
*s = Read-File-Into-Image("/path/to/image")
*g = ConvertToGrayScale(s)
*i = Invert Colors(g)
*b = ApplyGaussianBlur(i)
*result = Colour Dodge Blend Merge(b,g)
```

and tried

```
$im1->edgeImage(2);
$im1->contrastStretchImage(30, 500);
$im2 = $im1;
$im1->modulateImage(100, 20, 50); 
$im1->negateImage(FALSE);
$im1->gaussianBlurImage(5, 1, FALSE);
$im1->compositeImage($im2, imagick::COMPOSITE_COLORDODGE, 0, 0 );
```

still not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the radius should be larger than sigma. Else make it 0, so that sdk takes care. use a good quality image and format.
For reference..http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.sketchimage.php